# Make Checkstyle's suppresion rule file to ignore path separator

Tags: checkstyle, path-separator

We have a suppressions.xml file, where we used rules such as:

```xml
<suppress checks="JavadocPackage" files="/impl/"/>
```

This worked for anyone on Unix or Mac OS X. However on windows the files in that package don't match. We had to rewrite it as follows:

```xml
<suppress checks="JavadocPackage" files="[\\/]impl[\\/]"/>
```

However, this is ugly, especially with longer paths. Is there a trick to make it work with unix-style paths on Windows?

Comment: I created an issue with checkstyle for this: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/3744